# What does "dimensionality" mean for a numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy

I am still new to scikit-learn and numpy.
I read the tutorial, but I can't understand how they define array dimensions.

In the following example:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.arange(15).reshape(3, 5)
>>> a
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4],
       [ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
       [10, 11, 12, 13, 14]])
>>> a.shape
(3, 5)
>>> a.ndim
2
```

The array has five variables in each row, so I expect it to have 5 dimensions.

Why is `a.ndim` equal to 2?

Comment: It's the number of `[[` at the start of the `array` display.

Comment: `a.ndim == len(a.shape)`

Comment: I mistake the Frame and the Array, array is judged by how to find the number, how many steps to locate the number, in this case, you need locate the row and then locate the line. but in Frame, for one instance, this instance own a row, and all the lines in it described its attributes, or called it variables, or dimensions to define a instance. in Frame, you can use a two dimensions array to define a multi-dimension instance.

Comment: Don't forget that numpy handles *n*-dimensional arrays; e.g. `a = np.arange(60).reshape(3, 4, 5)` has `a.ndim = 3`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that you're using scikit learn, I'll explain this in the context of machine learning as it may make more sense...

Your feature matrix (which I assume is what you're talking about here), is going to be 2 dimensional typically (hence why `ndim = 2`) because you have rows (which occupy a 1 dimension) and columns (which occupy a second dimension)

In machine learning cases, I typically think of the rows as the samples and columns as the features.

Note, however, that each dimension can have multiple entries (e.g. you will have multiple samples/rows, and multiple columns/features). This tells you the size along that dimension.

So in your case:

```
>>> a
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4],
       [ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
       [10, 11, 12, 13, 14]])
>>> a.shape
(3, 5)
>>> a.ndim
2
```

You have one dimension that has a length/size of 3. And a second dimension that has 5 entries. You can think of this as a feature matrix containing 3 samples and 5 features/variables, for example.

All in all, you have 2 dimensions (`ndim = 2`), but the specific size of the array is represented by the shape tuple, which tells you how large each of the 2 dimensions are.

Furthermore, `(3,5,2)` will be a matrix with 3 dimensions, where the 3rd dimension has 2 values

I think the key here, at least in the 2 dimensional case, is to not think of it as nested lists or nested vectors (which is what it looks like when you consider the `[]`) but to just think of it as a table with rows and columns. The `shape` tuple and `ndim` will make more sense when you think of the data structure that way

Answer (score 0):

Dimension means there the length of a.shape tuple.
Shape of the ndarray is (3, 5) since it has 3 rows and 5 columns in it. This is exactly what you try to find, aren't you?

Answer (score 0):

I mistake the Frame and the Array, array is judged by how to find the number, how many steps to locate the number, in this case, you need locate the row and then locate the line. but in Frame, for one instance, this instance own a row, and all the lines in it described its attributes, or called it variables, or dimensions to define a instance. in Frame, you can use a two dimensions array to define a multi-dimension instance. 

`Array

1    4    5

2    3    6`

so it's two steps you will find the number, like you can you a[][] to locate
but in Frame
          `Length    Height    Weight

1        23           34           56

2        89           87           63`

This is a frame and actually is a 3-dimensional "array", but it's not an array.

Comment: What language uses `Frames`?  I wonder if the confusion has to do with a computer language other than Python (or MATLAB), or a language other than English (French?).

Comment: In `numpy` you normally index a 2d array with `a[i, j]`, though `a[i][j]` often works as well.

Comment: Are you talking about `pandas` dataframes?